# Hourly rates for a novice C# developer from Europe?

Tags: pay-rate, hourly

Okay so here is the deal,
I'm a 20 year old student of Computer Science @ University of Zagreb. But I have been active in the programming industry and I have 9 months of employment experience in a software company using C# and JavaScript for web and WinForms for a desktop application. I have also made several Android applications using Xamarin.Android and have made a few websites. None of them are currently hosted on GitHub but I would put them up as proof of my work. I was wondering what type of hourly rate should I ask for when applying for freelance jobs? Since I have <1 years of experience in the industry and sources vary greatly I would appreciate if any information about the expected rates. 
Note: I would be willing to work full-time.

Comment: There is no magic number, the sources vary greatly for a reason. See [From Agency to Freelance - What Should I Charge?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/from-agency-to-freelance-what-should-i-charge) as a general guide.

Comment: I believe this should be "*in* Europe", not "*from* Europe". Why would you get a different rate dependent on your nationality?

Comment: @CamilStaps The same Indian, Pakistani and Chinese developers don't have the same rates. Even more, it also depends on whether you live in the capital or in the suburb (costs of living).

Comment: @PeterMV You're also talking about in Europe.

Comment: @CamilStaps I am confused. Are we talking about the grammar or your question "Why would you get a different rate dependent on your nationality"? I was talking about later and was able to help this guy since were are coming from the same area (same nationality).

Comment: @PeterMV The only thing I was trying to point out is the ambiguity in "from Europe" - it can hint at both nationality and current location, while "in Europe" definitely means current location, which is, I believe, the intention of the question. (Sorry for my last brief message, I was on my phone, and running for a bus). Anyway, it's not that important: question answered, answer accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are coming from the same region, I may be able to reply as I am familiar with economic circumstances in the region.

As Stacey said, there is no magic number. You can put $50 per hour if you think you are so good. But with 9 months of experience, you are still a Junior.

If you bid via freelancing websites, I would go with $10 per hour and increase it with experience. Or start smaller jobs of a few weeks for  less than $500. Don't do large project for small money as you will never finish it and will only get a bad review.